# Grid disappears in view when returning to the same view after switching to another view from side menu in XDK

Tags: javascript, html, css, intel-xdk

I am developing a mobile app using Intel XDK. Basically it will show a grid of items based on categories that are set up in the side menu. So far the side menu is working and the grid is showing initially when the data loads. There are following problems:-

1. when the item in grid is clicked the details view is shown and a
   back button is there on top. But clicking on it opens the side menu
   instead of going back.
2. There are two entries in the side menu. clicking page 2 opens page
   two but when clicking the main entry the grid is missing.

The code is as follows:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--HTML5 doctype-->
<html>

<head>

    <title>App Framework Kitchen Sink</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimal-ui">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/appframework/icons.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/appframework/af.ui.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="lib/fastclick.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="lib/appframework/appframework.ui.min.js"></script>

    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <style>
        /* CSS responsive square grid */

        .grid-photo {
            margin: 3px -1px;
        }

        .grid-photo:after {
            content: '';
            display: block;
            clear: both;
        }

        .grid-photo li {
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            float: left;
            width: 10%;
            padding-bottom: 10%;
        }

        .grid-photo .grid-photo-box {
            position: absolute;
            left: 3px;
            right: 3px;
            top: 3px;
            bottom: 3px;
            background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.2);
            border: 1px;
            border-style: solid;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .grid-photo img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%
        }

        .grid-photo img:after {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            color: white;
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
            .grid-photo li {
                width: 12.5%;
                padding-bottom: 12.5%;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
            .grid-photo li {
                width: 16.6%;
                padding-bottom: 16.6%;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
            .grid-photo li {
                width: 25%;
                padding-bottom: 25%;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
            .grid-photo li {
                width: 33.3%;
                padding-bottom: 33.3%;
            }
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        function loadMore() {
            var list = document.getElementById("list");
            var row = document.createElement("li");
            var html = '<div class="grid-photo-box"><a href="#item1"><img src="total-core.jpg" /></a>Hello World!!</div>';
            row.innerHTML = html;
            list.appendChild(row);
        }
        function createMany() {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                loadMore();
            }
        }
    </script>

    <script>

        //        function fetchJSON(var url){
        //            var success=$.getJSON(url, function(data){
        //               alert(data) ;
        //            });
        //        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="splashscreen" class="ui-loader heavy">
        App Framework
        <br>
        <br>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-loading spin"></span>
        <h1>Starting app</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="view splitview">

        <header>
            <a class="menuButton" data-left-menu="left" data-transition="cover" style="float:left"></a>
            <h1>Title</h1>
        </header>

        <div class="pages">
            <div class="panel" id="main" data-title="Main" data-selected="true">
                <!--Initial Grid of items-->
                <div class="panel grid" data-title="Grid" id="grid" data-selected="true">
                    <div class="grid grid-photo" id="list">
                        <li>
                            <div class="grid-photo-box">
                                <a href="#item1"><img src="novafit.jpg" /></a>Hello world!!</div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="grid-photo-box">
                                <a href="#item2"><img src="total-core.jpg" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="grid-photo-box">
                                <a href="#item3"><img src="novafit.jpg" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="grid-photo-box">
                                <a href="#item4"><img src="total-core.jpg" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="grid-photo-box">
                                <a href="#item5"><img src="novafit.jpg" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="grid-photo-box">
                                <a href="#item6"><img src="total-core.jpg" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="grid-photo-box">
                                <a href="#item7"><img src="total-core.jpg" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="grid-photo-box">
                                <a href="#item8"><img src="novafit.jpg" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="grid-photo-box">
                                <a href="#item9"><img src="total-core.jpg" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="grid-photo-box">
                                <a href="#item10"><img src="novafit.jpg" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="grid-photo-box">
                                <a href="#item11"><img src="total-core.jpg" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="grid-photo-box">
                                <a href="#item12"><img src="novafit.jpg" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="grid-photo-box">
                                <a href="#item13"><img src="total-core.jpg" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="grid-photo-box">
                                <a href="#item14"><img src="novafit.jpg" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="grid-photo-box">
                                <a href="#item15"><img src="total-core.jpg" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="grid-photo-box">
                                <a href="#item16"><img src="novafit.jpg" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="grid-photo-box">
                                <a href="#item17"><img src="total-core.jpg" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="grid-photo-box">
                                <a href="#item18"><img src="novafit.jpg" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="grid-photo-box">
                                <a href="#item19"><img src="total-core.jpg" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="grid-photo-box">
                                <a href="#item20"><img src="novafit.jpg" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="grid-photo-box">
                                <a href="#item21"><img src="total-core.jpg" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="grid-photo-box">
                                <a href="#item22"><img src="novafit.jpg" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="grid-photo-box">
                                <a href="#item23"><img src="total-core.jpg" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="grid-photo-box">
                                <a href="#item24"><img src="novafit.jpg" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                    <a id="more" class="button block" onclick="createMany();">Load More</a>
                </div>


            </div>
            <div class="panel" id="page2" data-title="Page 2">
                This is Page 2
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Detail View Pages for each grid item-->
        <div class="panel" data-title="Item 1" id="item1">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 1</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" data-title="Item 2" id="item2">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 2</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" data-title="Item 3" id="item3">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 3</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" data-title="Item 4" id="item4">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 4</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" data-title="Item 5" id="item5">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 5</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" data-title="Item 6" id="item6">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 6</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" data-title="Item 7" id="item7">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 7</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" data-title="Item 8" id="item8">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 8</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" data-title="Item 9" id="item9">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 9</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" data-title="Item 10" id="item10">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 10</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" data-title="Item 11" id="item11">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 11</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" data-title="Item 12" id="item12">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 12</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" data-title="Item 13" id="item13">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 13</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" data-title="Item 14" id="item14">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 14</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" data-title="Item 15" id="item15">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 15</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" data-title="Item 16" id="item16">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 16</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" data-title="Item 17" id="item17">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 17</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" data-title="Item 18" id="item18">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 18</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" data-title="Item 19" id="item19">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 19</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" data-title="Item 20" id="item20">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 20</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" data-title="Item 21" id="item21">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 11</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" data-title="Item 22" id="item22">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 12</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" data-title="Item 23" id="item23">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 13</p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" data-title="Item 24" id="item24">
            <p>This is detail view for Item 14</p>
        </div>
        <nav id="left">
            <div class="view active">
                <header>
                    <h1>Left</h1>
                </header>
                <div class="pages">
                    <div class="panel active" id="navPage1" data-title="Foobar">
                        <ul class="list">
                            <li><a href="#main" onclick="$.afui.clearHistory()">Main Page</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#page2" onclick="$.afui.clearHistory()">Page Two</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should upcode with http://jsfiddle.net/ or link your websites